# Adding a new entry with Linq to XML at the right position (based on numerical attribute)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have come up with this function to save or update an entry in the XML file.

```
public void SetOutlineInfo(string talksdatabase, int talknumber, string languageCode, bool talkExcluded, DateTime dateExcudedFrom, string excludedNote)
{
    try
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(talksdatabase);
        var ptLang = doc.Descendants(languageCode).FirstOrDefault();
        if (ptLang != null)
        {
            var ptInfo = ptLang
                            .Descendants("PublicTalk")
                            .Where(p => p.Attribute("Number").Value == talknumber.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ptInfo != null)
            {
                ptInfo.Attribute("Excluded").Value = talkExcluded ? "true" : "false";
                ptInfo.Attribute("ExcludedFromDate").Value = dateExcudedFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                ptInfo.Attribute("ExcludedNote").Value = excludedNote;
            }
            else
            {
                ptLang.Add(new XElement("PublicTalk",
                    new XAttribute("Number", talknumber),
                    new XAttribute("Excluded", talkExcluded),
                    new XAttribute("ExcludedFromDate", dateExcudedFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                    new XAttribute("ExcludedNote", excludedNote)
                    ));
            }

            doc.Save(talksdatabase);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
    }
}
```

The only issue is that adding a new entry does not add it in the correct numerical position (the `Number` attribute).

I did some searching and they all show reading in records and sorting with `orderby`. But I am writing records.

---

As requested in the comments.

Here is an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublicTalkTitles>
  <eng>
    <PublicTalk Number="47" Excluded="true" ExcludedFromDate="2019-04-01" ExcludedNote="S-147 19.03" />
  </eng>
</PublicTalkTitles>
```

When a add a new entry, say talk number 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublicTalkTitles>
  <eng>
    <PublicTalk Number="1" Excluded="true" ExcludedFromDate="2023-09-12" ExcludedNote="1" />
    <PublicTalk Number="47" Excluded="true" ExcludedFromDate="2019-04-01" ExcludedNote="S-147 19.03" />
  </eng>
</PublicTalkTitles>
```

Comment: You could try XNode.AddAfterSelf (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.addafterself?view=net-7.0). It should be called on a PublicTalk node after which you want to add your element.

Comment: @LukaszNowakowski So I have to walk the existing node set to decide at what point to add it.

Comment: Please show your existing XML and what you want to change

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, yes.

Comment: Descendants returns an array.  So just add the index ptLang[0].Add

Comment: @jdweng No good. The list of talk info there might be more detailed. Eg 1,& 3 etc might already be there and I want to add 2. So you answer is based on the assumption I only want to do the one specific action of inserting an entry at the start. I don't. My question was to add an entry at the right position based on Number attribute value.

Comment: I assumed the WHERE was getting the correct index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first filter for all nodes which are `<= talknumber` then take `MaxBy` that number. You need to parse it to an `int` in order to do this filtering and sorting correctly.

Then that node is either:

- the one you want

  - Change it
- or the one before it

  - Use `AddBeforeSelf`
- or null

  - Use `AddFirst` on the parent.

---

```
    var ptLang = doc.Element("PublicTalkTitles").Element(languageCode);
    if (ptLang != null)
    {
        var pt = ptLang.Elements("PublicTalk");
        var ptInfo = pt
            .Where(p => int.Parse(p.Attribute("Number").Value) <= talknumber)
            .MaxBy(p => int.Parse(p.Attribute("Number").Value));
        if (int.Parse(ptInfo?.Attribute("Number").Value ?? "0") == talknumber)
        {
            ptInfo.Attribute("Excluded").Value = talkExcluded ? "true" : "false";
            ptInfo.Attribute("ExcludedFromDate").Value = dateExcudedFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            ptInfo.Attribute("ExcludedNote").Value = excludedNote;
        }
        else
        {
            var newElem = new XElement("PublicTalk",
                                    new XAttribute("Number", talknumber),
                                    new XAttribute("Excluded", talkExcluded),
                                    new XAttribute("ExcludedFromDate", dateExcudedFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                                    new XAttribute("ExcludedNote", excludedNote)
                                   );
            if (ptInfo != null)
                ptInfo.AddAfterSelf(newElem);
            else
                ptLang.AddFirst(newElem);
        }
    }
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KdlKzk)

If you don't have `MaxBy` you can instead use `OrderByDescending.FirstOrDefault` which is less efficient.

```cs
var ptInfo = pt
    .Where(p => int.Parse(p.Attribute("Number").Value) <= talknumber)
    .OrderByDescending(p => int.Parse(p.Attribute("Number").Value))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting a syntax error telling me that `MaxBy` is not available for me to use. I am using framework 4.6.2 and can't change that at this time.

Comment: OK you can use `OrderByDescending` see edit

Comment: Thanks,; I am just upgrading Visual Studio to latest version and then I will try this adjusted code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion to use `AddBeforeSelf` I have modified the function:

```
public void SetOutlineInfo(string talksdatabase, int talknumber, string languageCode, bool talkExcluded, DateTime dateExcudedFrom, string excludedNote)
{
    try
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(talksdatabase);
        var ptLang = doc.Descendants(languageCode).FirstOrDefault();
        if (ptLang != null)
        {
            var ptInfo = ptLang
                            .Descendants("PublicTalk")
                            .Where(p => p.Attribute("Number").Value == talknumber.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ptInfo != null)
            {
                ptInfo.Attribute("Excluded").Value = talkExcluded ? "true" : "false";
                ptInfo.Attribute("ExcludedFromDate").Value = dateExcudedFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                ptInfo.Attribute("ExcludedNote").Value = excludedNote;
            }
            else
            {
                var ptList = ptLang.Descendants("PublicTalk");
                bool bAdd = true;
                foreach ( var pt in ptList )
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(pt.Attribute("Number").Value) > talknumber)
                    {
                        pt.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("PublicTalk",
                            new XAttribute("Number", talknumber.ToString()),
                            new XAttribute("Excluded", talkExcluded),
                            new XAttribute("ExcludedFromDate", dateExcudedFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                            new XAttribute("ExcludedNote", excludedNote)
                            ));
                        bAdd = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(bAdd)
                {
                    ptLang.Add(new XElement("PublicTalk",
                        new XAttribute("Number", talknumber.ToString()),
                        new XAttribute("Excluded", talkExcluded),
                        new XAttribute("ExcludedFromDate", dateExcudedFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                        new XAttribute("ExcludedNote", excludedNote)
                        ));
                }
            }

            doc.Save(talksdatabase);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
    }
}
```